# Can we reference contents of <defs> across multiple <svg> elements?

Tags: html, svg

Can we reference the contents of defs contained in one `<svg>` from another `<svg>`?

Comment: What's the purpose ? You'll need to add ids to your elements declared in defs anyway, and yes, you can reference these elements in the whole document (that's why ids should be unique)

Comment: What do you mean? You can refer to the contents of the <defs> from any <svg> element, is that what you're asking?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yeah, that's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure you can... Just make one as a resource available to the others..

Example:

```css
#fire1 {
  fill: red;
}

#fire2 {
  fill: green;
}

#fire3 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Let's make it a resource :) -->
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0">
  <title>Re-Use SVG Defs as Resource</title>
 <defs>
   <g id="fire" transform="translate(0,10)">
     <path d="M101.138,160.949 C94.916,154.464 53.538,110.17 95.277,71.802 C130.054,39.868 135.137,13.003 123.434,-0 C123.434,-0 211.959,33.692 159.877,111.877 C150.998,125.163 128.702,140.843 140.369,173.129 L101.138,160.949 z" />
     <path d="M155.503,171.572 C153.624,165.019 145.142,150.746 171.021,122.303 C184.873,107.172 190.104,84.742 191.308,76.301 C191.308,76.301 237.167,100.662 191.576,160.215 L155.503,171.572 z" />
   </g>
 </defs>
</svg>


<svg id="fire1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <use xlink:href="#fire"/>
</svg>

<svg id="fire2" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <use xlink:href="#fire"/>
</svg>

<svg id="fire3" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <use xlink:href="#fire"/>
</svg>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/dpamPj)

If you're just trying to embed one svg into another (which would include the defs within it) you could also just plop in `image` into another svg like;

```
<svg id="fire1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
   <use xlink:href="#fire"/>
   <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="SomeOtherSVGImage.svg" />
</svg>
```

Comment: So you are referencing an element contained in a `<defs>` element, not the `<defs>` itself.

Comment: I misread, *a group **of** defs*, to *a group **or** defs*. And yes, defs can have an id, usefull for DOM manipulation, but it makes no sense to target it from a `<use>` element since its content is not displayed. As I said in a comment to an other answer, the only case I can think of where it could be usefull would be for `<style>` element, but it doesn't seem to work. Let's wait some insight from Mr Longson, or some clarification from OP.

Comment: @Kaiido Ha agreed, I often look forward to a good humbling from Rob

Answer (score -1):

Yes, by referring to the svg file in the `xlink:href` attribute of the `use` element.

```
<use xlink:href="path-to-file.svg#myDef" />
```

Comment: Are you sure it works ? The only case I can think of where it could be used would be to import a `<style>` element, but this doesn't seem to work. And all other cases would need direct references, which are not passed through the `<use>` element.

Comment: <use> renders things. <defs> itself is not renderable (though its contents may be).

Comment: That was the point, I was referring to an element defined in defs, not the defs in whole. I guess i should have expanded on the example.